# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am a student who is studying android by self.
This is my first question. Please help me.

```
09-12 01:35:35.723 2355-2355/com.example.jan.sanhakproject E/AndroidRuntime: 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.example.jan.sanhakproject, PID: 2355
                                                                                 com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.jan.sanhakproject.Chat
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zze(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.example.jan.sanhakproject.ChatActivity$2.onChildAdded(ChatActivity.java:115)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzblz.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbnz.zzYj(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzboc$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
    09-12 01:35:44.318 2355-2374/com.example.jan.sanhakproject W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
```

**Chat.java**

public class Chat {

```
    public String email;

    public String text;

    public Chat() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class)
    }

    public Chat(String text) {

        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

**ChatActivity.java**

```
    public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    String[] myDataset = {"안녕", "오늘","뭐했어","영화볼래?"};
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;


    EditText etText;
    Button btnSend;
    String email;
    List<Chat> mChat;
    FirebaseDatabase database;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();

        //database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        if (user != null) {
            // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
            email = user.getEmail();
        }

        Intent in = getIntent();
        final String stChatId = in.getStringExtra("friendUid");

        etText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etText);
        btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String stText = etText.getText().toString();

                if (stText.equals("") || stText.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "내용을 입력해 주세요.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, email + "," + stText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());


                    databaseReference = database.getReference("users").child(stChatId).child(formattedDate);

                    Hashtable<String, String> chat = new Hashtable<String, String>();
                    chat.put("email", email);
                    chat.put("text", stText);
                    databaseReference.setValue(chat);
                    etText.setText("");


                }


            }
        });


        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

        // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
        // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // use a linear layout manager
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mChat = new ArrayList<>();
        // specify an adapter (see also next example)
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(mChat, email, ChatActivity.this);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        databaseReference.child("users").child(stChatId).child("chats").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Chat chat = dataSnapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
                mChat.add(chat);


                mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(mChat.size() - 1);
                mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mChat.size() - 1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

**MyAdapter.java**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private String[] mDataset;
    List<Chat> mChat;
    String stEmail;
    Context context;

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView mTextView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mTextView);
        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public MyAdapter(List<Chat> mChat, String email, Context context) {
        this.mChat = mChat;
        this.stEmail = email;
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        if (mChat.get(position).getEmail().equals(stEmail)){
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 2;
        }
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v;
        if (viewType == 1) {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.right_text_view, parent, false);
        } else {
             v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false);
        }
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        holder.mTextView.setText(mChat.get(position).getText());
        holder.mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mChat.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: please specify your problem, On why did you get that error. We don't have much enough time to read whats the problem so you must specify it directly and simplify your codes, you don't need to post the codes that don't have a connection with the error.

Comment: I want to create a chat app in real time, but in the process of receiving the data, I'd like to make sure that I get the data. 
Caused by : java. lag. NullPointe rException : Can't match ' Failed ' in greeting 
An error is generated. 
I'm sorry.

Comment: you are trying to use an object reference that has the null value. or maybe Calling an instance method on the object referred by a null reference.

Comment: @Deee No `null` values seem involved here: "Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.jan.sanhakproject.Chat"

Comment: One of the nodes under the location that you're listening to in `databaseReference.child("users").child(stChatId).child("chats")`, does not implement the type that you're trying to read from it in `dataSnapshot.getValue(Chat.class)`. It's hard to say more without seeing the JSON at that location, which you can get by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: {
  "chats" : {
    "2017-09-10 16:42:10" : {
      "email" : "jilee317@naver.com",
      "text" : "lost"
    },
    "2017-09-10 16:42:30" : {
      "email" : "jilee317@naver.com",
      "text" : "Oh no "
    },
    "2017-09-10 16:44:02" : {
      "email" : "jilee317@naver.com",
      "text" : "asdfasdfasf"
    },
    "2017-09-11 02:11:20" : {
      "email" : "jilee317@naver.com",
      "text" : "hi"
    }
  
} Thank you for helping me, but I'm really beginning to be a novice. I don't understand the explanation very well.

Answer (score 0):

The exception log indicates the code is trying to get a value of object `Chat` and is finding a `String`.  The error occurs at this statement in `onChildAdded()`:

```
Chat chat = dataSnapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
```

Check your database to confirm that all children of `/users/stChatId/chats` are valid `Chat` objects. It looks like you are listening for new chats at:  `/users/stChatId/chats`:

```
databaseReference.child("users").child(stChatId).child("chats").addChildEventListener(...)
```

But are writing chats at this location:

```
databaseReference = database.getReference("users").child(stChatId).child(formattedDate);
```